# How can I get class, property, and method data from files without executing their code, similar to Reflection?

Tags: php

I have a bunch of PHP files with classes, in them (although I can't be 100% sure that they won't have code outside of classes in them too), and I need to parse these files to get information about the classes, such as the names of the classes, the methods, the properties, whether they are private/public/static, etc. I looked at PHP's reflection classes and this is very close to what I want but the reflection doesn't seem to use external files and it appears to need to define the classes first. I need to make sure that none of the code is executed and I will be editing the files so I can't guarantee that they will even be error-free.

Any suggestions?

Thanks.

Comment: You can't move the classes to their own files?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use Virtual Sandbox for this, it's a PECL extension. Additional information about this feature you can get at documentation for [Runkit_Sandbox](http://php.net/manual/en/runkit.sandbox.php)